# Autocomplete filter in react ant-design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an autocomplete component with object array as datasource. I managed to render the input and the dropdown of the options from the object array. I am having difficulties in filtering the results.
[enter link description here][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/viikas/pen/LzBoqr?editors=0010
```

Comment: filterOption={(inputValue, option) => option.props.children.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
filterOption={(inputValue, option) =>
  option.props.children.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}
```

instead of

```
filterOption={false}
```